# PHP Decoded JSON string from database return NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, google-api

I have my own website that using API from Google CSE (Custom Search Engine), because Google limited to 100 call per day for free user, so I want to store that JSON result from Google API to my database for the reason to save that my 100 call per day quota, so when the API ever called I just get from my database.

I want to print that JSON from my database into a looping

```
<?php
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jsondata WHERE id_jsondata = 1");
$jsondata = mysql_fetch_assoc($search);
$json = json_decode($jsondata['jsondata'], true);
foreach ($json as $data) {
echo $data['link'];
}
?>
```

But it doesnt happen, when I try to **var_dump($json)** it said NULL

The JSON is converted to string in my database, looks like this.

> `[{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Tekken 7 - Full-Length SDCC 2014 Trailer - YouTube","htmlTitle":"<b>Tekken 7</b> - Full-Length SDCC 2014 <b>Trailer</b> - YouTube","link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A","displayLink":"www.youtube.com","snippet":"Jul 25, 2014 ... Check out the full-length Tekken 7 trailer straight from the Bandai Namco Games 
>   Fighting Game Panel at San Diego Comic-Con 2014! Followu00a0...","htmlSnippet":"Jul 25, 2014 <b>...</b> Check out the full-length <b>Tekken 7 trailer</b> straight from the Bandai Namco Games <br>
>   Fighting Game Panel at San Diego Comic-Con 2014! Follow&nbsp;...","cacheId":"MmI6KIqGwI4J","formattedUrl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"width":"300","height":"168","src":"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-0L7ZLf24Vo2hFNsLE8awRPgmDlwznkynosWn71B-MX0u8-J4ZRuUgBnb"}],"imageobject":[{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTm6BV8RT9A/maxresdefault.jpg","width":"1280","height":"720"}],"person":[{"url":"http://www.youtube.com/user/NamcoBandaiGames"},{"url":"https://plus.google.com/117456562617165336918"}],"metatags":[{"title":"Tekken 7 - Full-Length SDCC 2014 Trailer","theme-color":"#e62117","og:site_name":"YouTube","og:url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A","og:title":"Tekken 7 - Full-Length SDCC 2014 Trailer","og:image":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTm6BV8RT9A/maxresdefault.jpg","og:description":"Check out the full-length Tekken 7 trailer straight from the Bandai Namco Games Fighting Game Panel at San Diego Comic-Con 2014! Follow Katsuhiro Harada on T...","al:ios:app_store_id":"544007664","al:ios:app_name":"YouTube","al:ios:url":"vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A&feature=applinks","al:android:url":"vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A&feature=applinks","al:android:app_name":"YouTube","al:android:package":"com.google.android.youtube","al:web:url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A&feature=applinks","og:type":"video","og:video:url":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/yTm6BV8RT9A","og:video:secure_url":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/yTm6BV8RT9A","og:video:type":"text/html","og:video:width":"1280","og:video:height":"720","og:video:tag":"namco bandai games","fb:app_id":"87741124305","twitter:card":"player","twitter:site":"@youtube","twitter:url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A","twitter:title":"Tekken 7 - Full-Length SDCC 2014 Trailer","twitter:description":"Check out the full-length Tekken 7 trailer straight from the Bandai Namco Games Fighting Game Panel at San Diego Comic-Con 2014! Follow Katsuhiro Harada on T...","twitter:image":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTm6BV8RT9A/maxresdefault.jpg","twitter:app:name:iphone":"YouTube","twitter:app:id:iphone":"544007664","twitter:app:name:ipad":"YouTube","twitter:app:id:ipad":"544007664","twitter:app:url:iphone":"vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A&feature=applinks","twitter:app:url:ipad":"vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A&feature=applinks"}],"videoobject":[{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTm6BV8RT9A","name":"Tekken 7 - Full-Length SDCC 2014 Trailer","description":"Check out the full-length Tekken 7 trailer straight from the Bandai Namco Games Fighting Game Panel at San Diego Comic-Con 2014! Follow Katsuhiro Harada on T...","paid":"False","channelid":"UC_ntXHv-XdKCD7CPynVvnQw","videoid":"yTm6BV8RT9A","duration":"PT3M9S","unlisted":"False","thumbnailurl":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTm6BV8RT9A/maxresdefault.jpg","embedurl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/yTm6BV8RT9A","playertype":"HTML5 Flash","width":"1280","height":"720","isfamilyfriendly":"True","regionsallowed":"AD,AE,AF,AG,AI,AL,AM,AO,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AW,AX,AZ,BA,BB,BD,BE,BF,BG,BH,BI,BJ,BL,BM,BN,BO,BQ,BR,BS,BT,BV,BW,BY,BZ,CA,CC,CD,CF,CG,CH,CI,CK,CL,CM,CN,CO,CR,CU,CV,CW,CX,CY,CZ,DE,DJ,DK,DM,DO,DZ,EC,EE,EG,EH...","interactioncount":"1444296","datepublished":"2014-07-25","genre":"Gaming"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yTm6BV8RT9A/maxresdefault.jpg"}]}}]`

The JSON string is so long, it contain 20 data, so I moved here http://codepad.org/Ib658BDD The JSON string example above just contain 1 data.

When I insert JSON to my database, I have encode the JSON already

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Tekken%207&cx=XXX&key=XXX");
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$json = $json['items'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO jsondata(jsondata) VALUES('".json_encode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', str_replace("'", "&#39;", $json)))."')");
```

Update:
It seem looks like because JSON data is not writen well
Now, I am strugling to remove " (quote symbol) inside data, for example

```
"snippet":"This video was taken from a facebook page, named "Dream Team Gaming"."
```

Comment: whatever json you gave here, is it what is inside $jsondata['jsondata'] or is it $jsondata?

Comment: @AshwinKJoseph for that example, I have a table called jsondata that have id_jsondata and jsondata column

Comment: Your json data is wrong, maybe it is caused by column's length is so short that can not store the complete json string.

Comment: @RazonYang The column length is no problem, I use longtext format

Comment: You have newlines in `snippet` and `htmlSnippet`.  If i remove them, i can feed your json to **[this online tool](http://jsonlint.com)** and validate it.

Comment: @RiyantoWibowo But the json string you provided above is incomplete. You can use some online json tool to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json data is not valid and incomplete. You must clear all wrong backslashes (\) and complete your data. If json string is not valid, json_decode command returns null. You can validate your json data on http://json.parser.online.fr/